# Performance hit from using std::find

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I have the following code to check whether a value belongs to a list of values. eg: `contains({1,2,3},3)`. Almost always, I could write a bunch of `if-else`s. How much performance hit does the `contains` approach create? Is there a way to avoid this?

```
template<typename T1,typename T2>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::initializer_list<T2>,T1>::value, bool> contains(const T1 &container,const T2 &item)
{
    return(std::find(container.begin(),container.end(),item)!=container.end());
}
```

Comment: I'd appreciate comments on what's wrong, before downvoting.

Comment: 1. Measure 2. Make clear how you measured 3. Then ask maybe.

Comment: What does "Almost always, I could write a bunch of if-elses" mean? Presumably, `find_if` also contains a bunch of "if-elses". Do you meant that you're going to always apply it to a tiny sequence of size known in advance?

Comment: @AmiTavory, the difference is that find_if contains **loop**. However, loop unrolling is to rescue, as I've shown in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With good optimizing compiler which knows how to unroll loops, you will end up with the pretty much same assembly and same performance.

Proof:

`find_if`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>

template<typename T1,typename T2>
bool contains(const T1 &container,const T2 &item) {
    return(std::find(container.begin(),container.end(),item)!=container.end());
}

bool foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
  return contains(std::initializer_list<int>({a, b, c, d, e}), 5);
}
```

Assembly:

```
foo(int, int, int, int, int):
        cmpl    $5, %edi        #, a
        je      .L6 #,
        cmpl    $5, %esi        #, b
        je      .L6 #,
        cmpl    $5, %edx        #, c
        je      .L6 #,
        cmpl    $5, %ecx        #, d
        je      .L6 #,
        cmpl    $5, %r8d        #, e
        sete    %al     #, D.75010
        ret
```

`if-else`:

```
bool foo(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  if (a == 5)
    return true;
  else if (b == 5)
    return true;
  else if (c == 5)
    return true;
  else if (d == 5)
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

Assembly:

```
foo(int, int, int, int):
        cmpl    $5, %edx        #, c
        sete    %dl     #, D.74611
        cmpl    $5, %ecx        #, d
        sete    %al     #, D.74611
        orl     %edx, %eax        # D.74611, D.74611
        cmpl    $5, %esi        #, b
        sete    %dl     #, D.74611
        orl     %edx, %eax        # D.74611, D.74611
        cmpl    $5, %edi        #, a
        sete    %dl     #, D.74611
        orl     %edx, %eax        # D.74611, D.74611
        ret
```